# How to set PolyLine Fit to our Google Map Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My polyline Going out of focus. I'm using  `map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 10));`
but this is not a solution. How to do slove this issue

[image]

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To solve your problem, lets first understand how the google map camera works. When you do:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 10));
```

The camera focuses the startlocation in the middle with 10 as the zoom level. What we need is to focus the route. For this we need to use the latLng bounds. Once we create a bound with two or more latLngs, we can set it to the camera of the map. This way your route is visible to your users.

Create a bound with all the start and end markers on your route:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(startMarker);
builder.include(endMarker);
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
```

Then obtain a movement description object by using the factory: `CameraUpdateFactory`:

```
int padding = 0; // padding around start and end marker
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

Comment: where i can apply this method. in On map Ready ?? @amalBit

Comment: add a gist on github. let me see. @DarshanKhatri

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Darshankhatri007/67105e7d66ada60be5a1d3f7b436a06c see @amlBit

Comment: you have done everything correct. Try adding some padding.. 200 or so.. check this project, i have added bounds to it.. https://github.com/amalChandran/google-maps-route-animation